# Calculating variance of OLS estimator with correlated errors due to repeated measurements

Tags: repeated-measures, panel-data, least-squares, autocorrelation, standard-error

Suppose there are $I$ people; half are male, half are female. We have measurements $y_{it}$ for individual $i$ at time $t \in \{0,1\}$, so there are two measurements per person, which are correlated.

Suppose the data are generated by the model

$$y_{it} = \beta_1+\beta_2 x_i + \epsilon_{it},$$

where $x_i \in \{0,1\}$ is a variable indicating person $i$'s gender (1 if female) and $\epsilon_{it}$ is an error term for which

$E[\epsilon_{it}]=0,$ for all $i,t$,

$\text{var}(\epsilon_{it})=E[\epsilon_{it}^2]=\sigma^2 ,$ for all $i,t$

$\text{cov}(\epsilon_{i0},\epsilon_{i1})=E[\epsilon_{i0}\epsilon_{i1}]=\sigma_{01} ,$ for all $i$, and zero otherwise. Let $\rho=\sigma_{01}/\sigma^2$ denote the correlation. The covariance matrix is then (for the observations grouped by person)

$$
\Omega=
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma^{2} & \sigma_{01}  & 0 & 0 & \cdots &0&0\\
\sigma_{01} & \sigma^{2}  & 0 & 0& \cdots & 0&0\\
0 & 0                       & \sigma^{2} & \sigma_{01}& \cdots &0&0\\
0 & 0                       & \sigma_{01} & \sigma^{2}& \cdots &0&0\\
\vdots &\vdots &  \vdots & \vdots & \hspace{0em} \ddots  & \vdots& \vdots\\
0 & 0   &0 & 0 & \ldots                         &\sigma^{2} &\sigma_{01}  \\
0 & 0   &0 & 0 & \ldots                        &\sigma_{01}&\sigma^{2} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Say we estimate $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ simply using OLS. In this case, OLS estimates $\hat\beta_1$ and $\hat\beta_2$ should remain unbiased, but their variance is not equal to $(X'X)^{-1}\sigma^2$ (with $X$ the $2I×2$ design matrix) like in standard OLS without correlated errors (serial correlation).

How to obtain the theoretical variance of the OLS estimator $\hat\beta_2$, expressed as a function of $X_i$, $\sigma^2$ and $\rho$?

*Adapted from:
Dunlop, Dorothy D. "Regression for longitudinal data: A bridge from least squares regression." The American Statistician 48.4 (1994): 299-303.*

*Note that paper has the answer (on the first page); I'm looking for the explanation.*

Answer (score 2):

The covariance matrix of the estimator that I derived is

$$ (X^TX)^{-1} X^T\Omega X (X^TX)^{-1}$$

It can be derived by like this:
$$\hat{\beta}= (X^TX)^{-1}(X^Ty)$$
$$E[\hat{\beta}]= (X^TX)^{-1}(X^TX\beta_{true})$$
$$\hat{\beta}-E[\hat{\beta}]= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T(y-X\beta_{true})=(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\epsilon$$
$$Cov(\hat{\beta})= E[(\hat{\beta}-E[\hat{\beta}])(\hat{\beta}-E[\hat{\beta}])^T]$$
$$Cov(\hat{\beta})= E[
(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \epsilon \epsilon^T X (X^TX)^{-1}]$$
$$Cov(\hat{\beta})= 
(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \Omega X (X^TX)^{-1}$$

Also if needed $X^T \Omega X$ can be easily rewritten in terms of $X_i$ $\sigma^2$ and $\rho$.

Comment: This is indeed the beginning of the answer, a derivation of the theoretical Newey-West standard errors. I was having a hard time in rewriting it in terms of Xi σ2 and ρ. But I got it now; I made a stupid mistake... if anyone wants the calculations I'm happy to provide them. But try for yourself first. Like sega_sai says, it's easy :)